# Find a Generating Function for Ordered Rooted Ternary Trees

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions, trees

**The Full Question**

If we let $T=$ the family of rooted ternary trees, $t_n =$ be number of trees in $T$ with $n$ nodes and $T(x) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}w_nx^n$ be the generating function of $T$.

A) Determine the values of $t_1,t_2,t_3$

B) Describe how once can decompose every tree in $T$ that has at least one node into a sequence of three smaller trees in $T$ plus the root node

C) Derive from B an equation that must be satisfied by $T(x)$. **Do not attempt to find a closed form**

**My Work**

$t_0 = 1,t_1=1,t_2=3,t_3=9$

I suppose if we consider any ternary tree of length $n$ then we have to think of ways we can connect a tree(s) to the root. I suppose I can have all my trees on the left, or all my trees on the right or all my trees in the middle. Or I can have all my trees on the left and middle, all left right, all middle right, or have them split middle left right. So I suppose if I made those all cases I could count it using Inclusion-Exclusion, but that seems like kind of a strange off the kilter approach to take. Could anyone help me find a better solution to part B?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Marko’s comprehensive answer is a bit overwhelming if you’ve not encountered that approach; let me see if I can offer one closer to what you’ve seen before.

Once you have a root, you can hang three trees from it: one is its left subtree, another is its centre subtree, and the third is its right subtree. (These are ordered trees, so *left*, *centre*, and *right* are meaningful here.) Any of these subtrees can of course be empty. Suppose that the left subtree has $i$ nodes, the centre one has $j$ nodes, and the right one has $k$ nodes, and you’re building a tree with $n$ nodes; then $i+j+k=n-1$, the root being the $n$-th node. This is the decomposition requested in part (B), and it gives you the recurrence

$$t_n=\sum_{\large{{0\le i,j,k}\atop{i+j+k=n-1}}}t_it_jt_k=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}t_i\sum_{j=0}^{n-1-i}t_jt_{n-1-i-j}\;.\tag{1}$$

The problem now is to convert this into an equation that $T(x)$ must satisfy.

The last summation in $(1)$ is clearly one term of the convolution of the sequence $\langle t_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ with itself; specifically, it’s the coefficient of $x^{n-1-i}$ in $\big(T(x)\big)^2$. The same reasoning shows that the entire right-hand side is the coefficient of $x^{n-1}$ in $\big(T(x)\big)^3$, so it’s the coefficient of $x^n$ in $x\big(T(x)\big)^n$. $(1)$ says that it’s also the coefficient of $x^n$ in $T(x)$, so to a first approximation we have $T(x)=x\big(T(x)\big)^3$. A little care is needed here, however, because $x\big(T(x)\big)^3$ has a $0$ constant term, and we know that $t_0=1$; thus, the correct relationship is

$$T(x)=1+x\big(T(x)\big)^3\;.$$

Note that with a bit more experience you won’t have to go through to convolution steps: you’ll be able to recognize that summing over $m$ indices whose sum is constant is basically taking an $m$-th power of the generating function.

Comment: Interesting commentary. Always an honor to work with you. (+1) (I left a comment on another one of your calculations from yesterday.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm not sure I understand the operation you did on the sum in the beginning where you first find a formula for $t_n$

Comment: @Dunka: Take a look at [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product) on the Cauchy product and see if it helps.

Answer (score 5):

The species here is $$\mathcal{T} = \epsilon + \mathcal{Z}\mathcal{T}^3$$
or alternatively $$\mathcal{T} = \epsilon + \mathcal{Z}\mathfrak{S}_{=3}(\mathcal{T})$$
 which gives the functional equation for the generating function
$$T(z) = 1 + z T(z)^3.$$
Extracting coefficients we get $t_0=1$ and for $n>0$
$$t_n = \sum_{p=0}^{n-1}\sum_{q=0}^{n-1-p} t_p t_q t_{n-1-p-q}$$
which gives the sequence
$$1, 1, 3, 12, 55, 273, 1428, 7752, 43263, 246675, 1430715,\ldots$$
which is [OEIS A001764](https://oeis.org/A001764).
A closed form is not difficult with Lagrange inversion.

**Addendum.** Here is the Lagrange inversion computation.
We seek
$$t_n  = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{n+1}} T(z) \; dz.$$
Put $T(z)=w$ so that $$z=\frac{w-1}{w^3} \quad\text{and}\quad
dz = \left(\frac{1}{w^3} - 3\frac{w-1}{w^4}\right) \; dw.$$
This gives for the integral
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w-1|=\epsilon} \frac{w^{3n+3}}{(w-1)^{n+1}} w
 \left(\frac{1}{w^3} - 3\frac{w-1}{w^4}\right)\; dw.$$
This has two components, namely
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w-1|=\epsilon} \frac{w^{3n+1}}{(w-1)^{n+1}}\; dw
\quad\text{and}\quad 
-3 \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w-1|=\epsilon} \frac{w^{3n}}{(w-1)^{n}}\; dw.$$
The first component is
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w-1|=\epsilon} 
\frac{1}{(w-1)^{n+1}} \sum_{q=0}^{3n+1}{3n+1\choose q} (w-1)^q\; dw$$
which is
$${3n+1\choose n}.$$
The second component is
$$-3 \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w-1|=\epsilon} 
\frac{1}{(w-1)^{n}}\; \sum_{q=0}^{3n}{3n\choose q} (w-1)^q\;dw$$
which is
$$-3\times {3n\choose n-1}.$$
Finally we can match this to the formula from the OEIS entry
obtaining
$${3n+1\choose n}-3\times {3n\choose n-1}
= \left(\frac{3n+1}{2n+1}-3\frac{n}{2n+1}\right){3n\choose n}$$
which yields
$$\frac{1}{2n+1} {3n\choose n}.$$

**Remark.**
An alternative interpretation of the question could be that the sequence / ordering where the trees are attached to the parent node does not matter. This produces $$\mathcal{T} = \epsilon + \mathcal{Z}\mathfrak{M}_{=3}(\mathcal{T})$$
which gives the functional equation for the generating function
$$T(z) = 1 + z 
\frac{1}{6} \left(T(z)^3 +3 T(z)T(z^2) + 2 T(z^3)\right)$$
because the cycle index of the multiset operator is
$$Z(S_3) = 1/6\,{a_{{1}}}^{3}+1/2\,a_{{2}}a_{{1}}+1/3\,a_{{3}}.$$

This gives the following recurrence:
$$t_n = \frac{1}{6}\sum_{p=0}^{n-1}\sum_{q=0}^{n-1-p} t_p t_q t_{n-1-p-q}
+\frac{1}{2} \sum_{p=0}^{\lfloor (n-1)/2\rfloor} t_{p} t_{n-1-2p}
+ \frac{1}{3} [[n-1 \equiv 0\bmod 3]] t_{(n-1)/3}.$$
which yields the sequence
$$1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 8, 17, 39, 89, 211, 507, 1238, 3057, 7639, 19241,\ldots$$
which is [OEIS A000598](https://oeis.org/A000598) where we find this computation confirmed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm pretty confused about your notation (All of it before "Extracting coefficients we get..")

Comment: The notation is documented at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_combinatorics).

Comment: I'm (slowly!) learning from your answers, so I always appreciate them; of course I upvoted, and I really don't understand the downvotes.

Comment: Very kind of you, did you see my other comment?

Comment: I think this is a useful answer to someone looking for this type of a solution. It requires a more advanced knowledge of math, but that doesn't imply it is useless to everyone.